# What do these different usages of ‘import’ represent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newcomer on React, I'm a Little confused about how "import" statements are written. Until now I've seen this 4 styles:

`/* This is very clear to me - Here no Problem */
  import React from 'react';`

`/* What does "./" before ListContacts mean? */
  import ListContacts from './ListContacts'`

`/* What "*" and "as" mean on this import statement? */
  import * as ContactsAPI from './utils/ContactsAPI'`

`/*What does { } mean on this import statement? */
 import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

Thanks very much for your time

Comment: These are javascript import statements and aren't react specific. They all serve different purposes. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import As for the `./` those are relative pathnames.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ListContacts from './ListContacts'
```

'./'  means it's a component that's not in node_modules. Usually ones you've built yourself.

```
import * as ContactsAPI from './utils/ContactsAPI'
```

* means you are importing all named exports (so you can use them by name)

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

{ BrowserRouter }means that you are only importing the component named BrowserRouter from more than one named export.

Comment: Expanding on this answer, `import` and `export` relate more to ES6 JavaScript than directly to React, and are not supported in many older versions of browsers.

This article explains in more detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import